# Require own custom Class file using Laravel's built in function in Laravel4

Tags: php, class, validation, laravel-4

I got a custom class file, just for my own custom function.

I need to use Laravel's Validator's function inside my custom class file,

I'd try extends, use namespace etc, and not working as expected.

I'm not sure how extact / proper way to use a own custom class/helper file, please guide.

```
class SessionsController extends \BaseController {

   function __construct()
   {
       //Include my class file @ app/_extra/custom_validator.php
       require_once app_path('_extra/custom_validator.php');

   }

}
```

And here's my validator class file

```
 class custom_validator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator
 {

     public function validate($input,$rules){
         $validation = Validator::make($input,$rules);
         if($validation->passes())return true;
         return $validation->messages();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your custom classes, you can have a separate folder in your app directory named after your project. Within that folder you can have your custom validators.

Say you have an app/Project/Validators folder and inside that folder your custom_validator class. Define your class and namespace like this

```
<?php namespace Project\Validators;

 class CustomValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator
 {

     public function validate($input,$rules){
         $validation = Validator::make($input,$rules);
         if($validation->passes())return true;
         return $validation->messages();
     }
 }
```

Then go to your composer.json and have this directory autoload

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Project\\": "app/Project"
    }
}
```

When you want to use that class, you can reach it from its own namespace:

First address the namespace in your controller:

```
use Project\Validators\CustomValidator;
```

and then you can instantiate the class like this:

```
$validator = new CustomValidator();
```

Way better than actually requiring the file from the filesystem yourself.
And do not forget to do

```
composer dump-autoload
```

when you update your composer.json.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your composer.json, you can add your file to the classmap object of the autoload object. Or if you have a directory full of files you want to autoload, you can add it to the PSR-0 or PSR-4 autoload object like so:

```
...
"autoload": {
  ...
  "psr-0": {
    "Acme": "app/Acme"
  }
...
```

This will load all classes inside app/Acme for use in your application.